# Inside the function >>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, function

This is a code to validate a credit card number regarding to given requirements. I made the code in a way that fits all check functions in the main function and it is working well in that way. However I wanted to tidy up my code a bit and make it better practice so the code is like this now. I think I have a part of functions that I still couldn't understand fully. Can you please tell me what is my mistake here?
Any input appreciated.

```js
'use strict';
let cardNumLength = getLength();
let isNumOnly = /^\d+$/.test(cardNum);
let isLastDigitEven = isEndEven();
let isSumValid = isSumGreaterThan16();
let allDigitsNotSame = allEqualCheck(cardNum);
let errorArray = [];

function cardNumValidator(cardNum) {
    if (cardNumLength, isNumOnly, isLastDigitEven, isSumValid, allDigitsNotSame) {
        console.log(`"${cardNum}" is a valid credit card number.`);
        return
    }
    return errorArray;
}

// getLength function to check if the number has 16 digits
function getLength(cardNum) {
    //console.log(cardNum.length); //debugging
    if (cardNum.length == 16) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// to check the final digit if its even
function isEndEven(cardNum) {

    if (cardNum[cardNum.length - 1] % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// to check if the sum of the digits are greater than 16
function isSumGreaterThan16(cardNum) {
    let intCardNum = parseInt(cardNum);
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cardNum.length; i++) {
        sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(cardNum[i]); //parseInt() converts string into number
    }
    if (sum > 16) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function allEqualCheck(cardNum) {
    if (cardNum.split('').every(char => char === cardNum[0])) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* using switch statement to final validation regarding to the requirements those checked seperately by previous inner functions*/
function isValidError() {
    if (cardNumLength === false) {
        errorArray.push('Number must be 16 digits!');
    } else if (isNumOnly === false) {
        errorArray.push('Invalid characters!');
    } else if (isLastDigitEven === false) {
        errorArray.push('Odd final number!');
    } else if (isSumValid === false) {
        errorArray.push('Sum less than 16!');
    } else if (allDigitsNotSame === false) {
        errorArray.push('All numbers can not be the same!');
    }
    return errorArray;
}
cardNumValidator('9999777788880000'); //valid number example
cardNumValidator('6666666666661666'); //valid number example

cardNumValidator('a92332119c011112'); //Invalid number example
cardNumValidator('4444444444444444'); //Invalid number example
cardNumValidator('1111111111111110'); //Invalid number example
cardNumValidator('6666666666666661'); //Invalid number example
```

Comment: `getLength` expects an argument `cardNum` which you're not providing in `let cardNumLength = getLength();` . So you're calling the function without providing a card number, hence the length of undefined error because cardNum is not defined

Comment: What is `cardNum`?

Comment: You are not passing `cardNum` here either: `isEndEven(); isSumGreaterThan16();`

Comment: ok. Edited the code. Took the function assignments to variables into the main function. And made some other changes. But now I just couldn't get checked the numbers that passed to the main function.

Answer (score 0):

In the very first line you are not passing any arguments to the `getLength` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using global variables like you did, but set them depending on the cardNum.
The cardNumValidator function will now always return an error array, which will have length zero when there is no error. When there are multiple errors, the errorArray will have all of them, not just a single one.

```js
'use strict';
let cardNumLength = false;
let isNumOnly = false;
let isLastDigitEven = false;
let isSumValid = false;
let allDigitsNotSame = false;
let errorArray = [];

function cardNumValidator(cardNum) {
 cardNumLength = getLength(cardNum);
 isNumOnly = /^\d+$/.test(cardNum);
 isLastDigitEven = isEndEven(cardNum);
 isSumValid = isSumGreaterThan16(cardNum);
 allDigitsNotSame = allEqualCheck(cardNum);

 errorArray = [];
 isValidError();

    if (errorArray.length == 0) {
        console.log(`"${cardNum}" is a valid credit card number.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`"${cardNum}" is an invalid credit card number.`);
        console.dir(errorArray);
    }
    return errorArray;
}

// getLength function to check if the number has 16 digits
function getLength(cardNum) {
    //console.log(cardNum.length); //debugging
    if (cardNum.length == 16) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// to check the final digit if its even
function isEndEven(cardNum) {

    if (cardNum[cardNum.length - 1] % 2 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// to check if the sum of the digits are greater than 16
function isSumGreaterThan16(cardNum) {
    let intCardNum = parseInt(cardNum);
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cardNum.length; i++) {
        sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(cardNum[i]); //parseInt() converts string into number
    }
    if (sum > 16) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function allEqualCheck(cardNum) {
    if (cardNum.split('').every(char => char === cardNum[0])) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* using switch statement to final validation regarding to the requirements those checked seperately by previous inner functions*/
function isValidError() {
    if (cardNumLength === false) {
        errorArray.push('Number must be 16 digits!');
    }
    if (isNumOnly === false) {
        errorArray.push('Invalid characters!');
    }
    if (isLastDigitEven === false) {
        errorArray.push('Odd final number!');
    }
    if (isSumValid === false) {
        errorArray.push('Sum less than 16!');
    }
    if (allDigitsNotSame === false) {
        errorArray.push('All numbers can not be the same!');
    }
    return errorArray;
}
cardNumValidator('9999777788880000'); //valid number example
cardNumValidator('6666666666661666'); //valid number example

cardNumValidator('a92332119c011112'); //Invalid number example
cardNumValidator('4444444444444444'); //Invalid number example
cardNumValidator('1111111111111110'); //Invalid number example
cardNumValidator('6666666666666661'); //Invalid number example
```